# Trouble getting results back from mssql database

Tags: php, html, sql-server

I have a problem whenever I query and display my resulted items. I am using PHP and MSSQL for my database. I have no problem when I query from the database but when I added an "if" statement so that to display "NO RECORDS FOUND" the problem arises.

Here's my code where I think the problem is:

//Show results in table

```
  if(sqlsrv_num_rows($result)>0){

    $o = '<table id="myTable">
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age </th>
        <th>Sex</th>
        </tr>
        </thead><tbody>';

    while ( $record = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result) )
        {

            $o .= '<tr><td>'.$record ['Name'].'</td><td>'.$record ['Age'].'</td><td>'.$record ['Sex'].'</td></tr>';
        }               

    $o .= '</tbody></table>';

    echo $o;

  }

  else{

    echo "No records found";

  }
```

whenever I search for a data it always display No records found even if the data is stored in the database. Help please? newbie here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of [sqlsrv_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-num-rows.php):

> This function requires that the statement resource be created with a static or keyset cursor.

Make sure you create your query like this (note the SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET option):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Table_1";
$params = array();
$options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
$result = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql , $params, $options );
```

The reason for this, is that the default option (SQLSRV_CURSOR_FORWARD), only fetches the records from the database one row at a time. This means that the sqlsrv_num_rows function does not know the number of rows, when it is called before any rows are fetched.

Comment: You're welcome. If my reply helped you, consider marking it as an answer for your question.